# Laravel Undefined index foreach at blade.php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

Im very new to Laravel. i have found this confusing error when im using Controller and newly created blade.php

This is my Controller

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
            $users[] = [
            '0' => [
                'first_name' => 'James',
                'last_name' => 'Bond',
                'location' => 'UK'
            ],
            '1' => [
                'first_name' => 'Jimmy',
                'last_name' => 'Carter',
                'location' => 'USA'
            ]
        ];

        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

This is my index.blade.php file

```
@if (count($users) > 0)
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <li>{!! $user['first_name'] !!}</li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

I'm getting following error always. as i know im passing the $user object correctly to the blade.php . but i cannot figure out what is the wrong

```
ErrorException in f1adbf0485f192729c60772e5dc5b16ad0234be2.php line 3:
Undefined index: first_name (View: /Users/Mac/Development/PHP/Laravel/Lara53/resources/views/admin/users/index.blade.php)
in f1adbf0485f192729c60772e5dc5b16ad0234be2.php line 3
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/Mac/Development/PHP/Laravel/Lara53/storage/framework/views/f1adbf0485f192729c60772e5dc5b16ad0234be2.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'users' => array(array(array('first_name' => 'James', 'last_name' => 'Bond', 'location' => 'UK'), array('first_name' => 'Jimmy', 'last_name' => 'Carter', 'location' => 'USA'))))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/Users/Mac/Development/PHP/Laravel/Lara53/resources/views/admin/users/index.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'users' => array(array(array('first_name' => 'James', 'last_name' => 'Bond', 'location' => 'UK'), array('first_name' => 'Jimmy', 'last_name' => 'Carter', 'location' => 'USA'))))) in View.php line 149
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function index(){
        $users = [
        '0' => [
            'first_name' => 'James',
            'last_name' => 'Bond',
            'location' => 'UK'
        ],
        '1' => [
            'first_name' => 'Jimmy',
            'last_name' => 'Carter',
            'location' => 'USA'
        ]
    ];

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use $`users[] = array()`, so `$users[0]` save the array. In you blade should like this, or implemented as Paul Androschuk's answer.

```
@if (count($users[0]) > 0)
    @foreach($users[0] as $user)
        <li>{!! $user['first_name'] !!}</li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your foreach open and closed this way

```
@foreach( $recibos as $recibo)

@endforeach
```

in my case my error was I put `@foreach` to end